# How to trigger this event " browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener() " using Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I just did a simple Firefox extension. Whenever I click a extention_button on my Firefox browser. So the event delivers the message to my application.

background.js

```
   

     /*
        On startup, connect to the "ping_pong" app.
        */
        console.log("going to connect with applic");
        var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");
        console.log("connected successfully");
        
        /*
        Listen for messages from the app.
        */
        port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
          console.log("Received: " + response);
        });
        
        /*
        On a click on the browser action, send the app a message.
        */
        browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
          console.log("Sending:  ping");
          port.postMessage("ping");
        });
```

How to trigger this event `browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(()` in Firefox extension using Javascript?

Comment: This event is triggered only by clicking the extension icon.

Comment: Is there is any way to do this operation "port.postMessage("ping");" without this event browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener().. Waiting for your reply!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Of course it's possible. Simply do it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks man. You helped me a lot.

Comment: My work had been completed. Thanks a lot man.